# ICS class not found Exception

Tags: android, sdk

I had updated my android sdk to ics(4.1) as i updated all my old projects which were developped in froyo(2.3) giving me error Like

```
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.def/com.abc.def.defMain}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.def.defMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.abc.def-1.apk]
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.def.defMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.abc.def-1.apk]
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-16 19:16:32.284: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  ... 11 more
```

before updating sdk all of these were running very without any error please help

Comment: this class is not found in your source project `com.abc.def.defMain`

Comment: but this was an running project

Comment: try to specify in `AndroidManifest.xml` `<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="7"/>`

Comment: this tag is allready added in my manifest file

Comment: Can you post your code so we can get a better idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this Exception this problem was occuring because i was using external libraries in my project and reffering them in build path but in ics the libraries should be contained in libs directory of project so as i copied the libraries in libs problem get solved